# Merge two .doc files in a single one (translation face to face)

Tags: microsoft-word

I have two doc files, one in italian and the other one in english, and I'd like to merge those file in a single file dividing the page in two columns keeping, more or less, a connection between rows: row 1 of the italian file should be aligned with row 1 of the english file.

Any hints to achieve this in a simple way?

Thanks!

Comment: a start would be modifying the margins on both and defining a two column layout.  there might be a way to programmatically then cut pages in....no specifics so it's a comment not an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inswert a 2 X 1 table, cut and paste the Italian text on one side and then the English text on the other. That is probably the simplest way.....